# How to read and write pandas/pyspark dataframe to Snowflake

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to populate a snowflake table using the pandas dataframe that I have created. I have the connection to Snowflake - how do I write pandas dataframe to a Snowflake table?

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake has connectors for all most everything same for python

```
pip install snowflake-connector-python
```

then you can use

write_pandas() or use standard  pandas.DataFrame.to_sql()